# How to combine two show graphics together?

Tags: graphics3d

I have plotted two graphics, but I don't know how to combine them.

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.8], Red, Arrowheads[0.08], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 1.2}, {0, 0, 2}}, 0.04]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0.3, 0, -1.2}, {0.8, 0, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3, 0, -1.2}, {-0.8, 0, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0.3, -1.2}, {0, 0.8, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, -0.3, -1.2}, {0, -0.8, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, 0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, 
       0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, 0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {-0.8 Sqrt[2]/2,
        0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {0.8 Sqrt[2]/
        2, -0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {-0.8 Sqrt[2]/
        2, -0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.005]]}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.8, 0.14, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]]], 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]]], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]]], 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]]], 0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.805, 0.16, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π/4], 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π/4], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π/4], 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π/4], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.81, 0.18, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π/2], 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π/2], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π/2], 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π/2], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.815, 0.2, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 3 π/4], 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 3 π/4], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 3 π/4], 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 3 π/4], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.82, 0.22, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π], 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π], 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + π], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.825, 0.24, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 5 π/4], 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 5 π/4], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 5 π/4], 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 5 π/4], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.83, 0.26, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 3 π/2], 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 3 π/2], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 3 π/2], 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 3 π/2], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.835, 0.28, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 7 π/2], 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 7 π/2], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 7 π/2], 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 7 π/2], 0}}},
    {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.84, 0.3, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 2 π], 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 2 π], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 2 π], 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{0, 2 π}, 5]] + 2 π], 0}}}}, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, SphericalRegion -> True], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x = 1.5 Cos[10 t], y = 1.5 Sin[10 t], 
   z = t}, {t, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.3], {RGBColor[0.1, 0.7, 0.5], 
     Tube[{0.1, 0.1}]}}]]
```

---

```
Show[Graphics3D[{{Sphere[{4, 0, 0}, 0.8]}, Red, Arrowheads[0.08], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0 + 4, 0, -1.2}, {0 + 4, 0, -2}}, 0.04]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0.3 + 4, 0, -1.2}, {0.8 + 4, 0, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3 + 4, 0, -1.2}, {-0.8 + 4, 0, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0 + 4, 0.3, -1.2}, {0 + 4, 0.8, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0 + 4, -0.3, -1.2}, {0 + 4, -0.8, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0.3 Sqrt[2]/2 + 4, 
       0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {0.8 Sqrt[2]/2 + 4, 
       0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3 Sqrt[2]/2 + 4, 
       0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {-0.8 Sqrt[2]/2 + 4, 
       0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0.3 Sqrt[2]/2 + 4, -0.3 Sqrt[2]/
        2, -1.2}, {0.8 Sqrt[2]/2 + 4, -0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.005]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3 Sqrt[2]/2 + 4, -0.3 Sqrt[2]/
        2, -1.2}, {-0.8 Sqrt[2]/2 + 4, -0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 
     0.005]]}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.8, 0.14, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]]] + 4, 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]]], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]]] + 4, 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]]], 0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.805, 0.16, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π/4] + 4, 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π/4], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π/4] + 4, 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π/4], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.81, 0.18, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π/2] + 4, 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π/2], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π/2] + 4, 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π/2], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.815, 0.2, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 3 π/4] + 4, 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 3 π/4], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 3 π/4] + 4, 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 3 π/4], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.82, 0.22, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π] + 4, 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π] + 4, 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + π], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.825, 0.24, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 5 π/4] + 4, 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 5 π/4], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 5 π/4] + 4, 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 5 π/4], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.83, 0.26, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 3 π/2] + 4, 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 3 π/2], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 3 π/2] + 4, 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 3 π/2], 
       0}}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.835, 0.28, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 7 π/2] + 4, 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 7 π/2], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 7 π/2] + 4, 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 7 π/2], 0}}},
    {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.84, 0.3, 
      0.1], {{2 Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 2 π] + 4, 
       2 Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 2 π], 
       0}, {Cos[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 2 π] + 4, 
       Sin[Dynamic[Clock[{2 π, 0}, 5]] + 2 π], 0}}}}, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, SphericalRegion -> True], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x = 4 + 1.5 Cos[10 t], y = 1.5 Sin[-10 t], 
   z = t}, {t, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.3], {RGBColor[0.1, 0.7, 0.5], 
     Tube[{0.1, 0.1}]}}]]
```

Comment: `Show[℅, ℅℅]`? ____

Comment: Yeah, Thanks...

Comment: @JasonB  Sorry. This will make the rotation of the two balls the same. But separately they are rotating in the opposite direction.

Comment: Try `Animate` separately to your rotating ball and combine them by GraphicsRow?